# How/when mysql compiles stored procedures?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

We intend to use mysql stored procedures for handling all database work for one project.
There are several applications(different languages) using same database and I am fairly sure that there is nice amount of repeated SQL code across those apps.

And then while reading something about mysq I stumbled upon
http://www.joinfu.com/2010/05/mysql-stored-procedures-aint-all-that/
Article basically says that stored procedures are compiled each time when new db connection is made.
Will mysql compile ALL(3 digits number at least) stored procedures on database?

Comment: I would say that the article you linked answers your question.

Comment: Yeah, i would say that too. It is just that I had sort of hope that something like "Oh, thats not true for ver 5.5 and later of mysql".

Comment: In the comments of your linked article a discussion evolves with the essence, that things have improved in 5.5 while not blatantly so

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Query and stored procedures are compiled on demand and then kept in a cache for a while. If you use a specific stored procedure repeatedly the version compiled in the cache will be used, but if it is no longer in cache it must be compiled first, *just like any other query* you send to a database.

What MySQL certainly will not do is compile all x-hundred stored procedures at once - in case that was what you were afraid of.

But all this is somewhat irrelevant The advantage of stored procedures is that you can make sure that multiple applications using the same database, use it in the same way. When your performance is such that you start looking at the compilation cache for speed, you are looking at the wrong place. Speed optimization is better done through either query or database redesign.

Comment: Databases need to be blindingly fast. After you have optimized your queries and database design and indexes, **how** else can you furthur optimize it for speed?

Comment: Faster hardware, larger in memory caches, faster hard drives, other storage engines. Of course this is after you added indices to speed up the queries, etc... Also be aware of locks: when a table's content is changed all the time it is locked for every change, thus holding up queries. There is a whole science behind this and if I were you I'd make this a new question and not add a comment to a 4 year old answer as there are many answers to this question.

Answer (score 4):

MySQL will not  compile all stored procedures at once. They will be executed on demand like queries as per requirement and when you call them.

With a stored procedure, however, the database compiles the query plan once and reuses the compiled process. This pre-compilation can yield a significant performance advantage.